# Fill a End_date Column with next row's Start_date in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below (Slowly changing Dimension). I want to fill end_dt column with the next row start_dt for a particular group identified by key column.

```
Key start_dt   end_dt
1   25-05-2019 NA
1   30-06-2019 NA
1   15-07-2019 NA
2   17-07-2019 NA
2   15-07-2019 NA
```

I want the data to be populated for end_dt as below.

```
Key start_dt   end_dt
1   25-05-2019 30-06-2019
1   30-06-2019 15-07-2019
1   15-07-2019 NA
2   17-07-2019 NA
2   15-07-2019 17-07-2019
```

What i tried is as below. I have generated a sequence for each key group starting with 2 after sorting start_dt ascending. And then created a new dataframe with start_dt and same key column, and then sorting them based on start_dt, then creating a sequence for key group starting with 1.

Then joined these two dataframes with the sequence column.  Please help for an optimal solution.

```
df.sort_values(['start_dt'],ascending=[True],inplace=True)
df['seq'] = df.groupby(['key']).cumcount() + 2

temp= pd.DataFrame(df)
temp.sort_values(['start_dt'],ascending=[True],inplace=True)
temp=temp.rename(columns = {'start_dt':'end_dt'})
temp['seq'] = temp.groupby(['key']).cumcount() + 1

df = pd.merge(df, temp[['key','seq','end_dt']],how='left', on=['key','seq'])
```

Comment: But why does the first date for key=2, not have `15-07-2019`? i.e the following row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you first need to [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) both by `Key` and `start_dt`, and then you can use [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to assign the following `start_dt`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Key', 'start_dt'])
df['end_dt'] = df.groupby('Key').start_dt.shift(-1)

print(df.reset_index(drop=True))

    Key    start_dt      end_dt
0    1  15-07-2019  25-05-2019
1    1  25-05-2019  30-06-2019
2    1  30-06-2019         NaN
3    2  15-07-2019  17-07-2019
4    2  17-07-2019         NaN
```

Comment: My solution (obviously not as good) involved shifting start_dt (to get end_dt) and Key, then comparing Key and shifted key values to generate NaNs. I try to figure out how your solution (grouping) works, I cannot understand how the NaNs are created. If I do df['end_dt'] = df.groupby('Key').start_dt.shift(0) the same list with start_dt is created...

Comment: Okay, let me know if you have any doubts  @NeofytosBoufidis

Comment: There are no doubts, it works perfectly fine I just cannot understand how the grouping works to create the NaNs in your solution... @yatu

Comment: Thanks very much, I was here to answer the question, it is actually posted by another SO member. Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: You're welcome :) and again, don't forget to accept. The green check under the voting sings @NeofytosBoufidis